# Notepad++ has sticky tabs in Linux Mint

Tags: notepad++, linux-mint, tabs

Running Notepad++ I want to rearrange the tab bar. On my Windows machine a long click and drag works fine. Using Linux Mint if I long click on the tab it becomes sticky to the mouse cursor. I can't find any way to unstick it, so I can't change tabs within that view. The other view is unaffected.

I use Multi-line tabs with coloured bar and a close button.  They are normally not locked. Once the sticky behaviour has started locking has no effect.  The only way I've found to stop it is to close N++ and start again.

I can't see any settings that are different between the two installations. I don't know if this is a bug in the Mint version or user error.  Can anyone suggest either or both of:

how to unstick the cursor so I can change tabs and actually do some work!

how to ensure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Installed unofficially on Mint using the method shown at https://itsfoss.com/notepad-plus-plus-linux/

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you have a trackpad (on a laptop), you may wish to try disabling it temporarily and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Disabling the trackpad made no difference.  Thanks anyway.